# Postgresql: Issue when updating value into one column which is text datatype

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have one table, that have one field (item_value) which is a text data type, and i am trying to update through psql:

```
UPDATE table1 SET item_value="{ value:'BOX',id:'2580'}" where id=643
```

this query shows

```
 column "{ value:'BOX',id:'2580'}" does not exist
```

But when i do it from rails console, this will work

```
t = Table1.find 643
t.item_value = "{ value:'BOX',id:'2580'}"
t.save

t.item_value.class
=> String
```

Any issue with that query? anything needs to do with cast

Comment: Try to swap quotes.

Answer (score 5):

This is occurring because you are using `"` instead of `'`. Try using:

```
UPDATE table1 SET item_value='{ value:"BOX",id:"2580"}' where id=643
```

Because of this, you will need to change the quotes within the JSON string to be `"`